# How to install SharePoint 2010 on Windows 2012 R2

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, windows-server-2012-r2

I tried installing SharePoint 2010 on Windows 2012 R2 Server but PreReqInstaller is not working. Can anyone guide me in this install?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the SP2 slipstream media for installing SharePoint 2010 on Windows Server 2012 R2.

To get a supported environment you then need to update to at least February 2014 CU

Read more here:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2014/05/03/sharepoint-2010-sp2-and-windows-server-2012-r2.aspx

Comment: I tried to find the slipstream version for SharePoint 2010 Enterprise but cant find..if I have the SP 2010 Enterprise media and SP2 can I slipstream by myself? if yes then how.

Comment: No you can not do it yourself, you can find it in VLSC

Comment: so far found slipstream for foundation ...do u know where can i find the enterprise version?